# Celery Flower as Daemon

Tags: celery, tornado, flower

Im running celery with a redis backend.
I want to run celery flower as a daemon on centos 6.2.

I understand flower is a Tornado application , so I should use a process to run a tornado application as a deamon.

Normally to start flower I use this command:

> celery flower --broker=redis://localhost

I read at the below link that I need to create a python script as such:
http://www.charleshooper.net/blog/python-starting-tornado-apps-at-boot-using-upstart/
(Startflower.py)

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import tornado.httpserver 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
    http_server.listen(port)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

However, I am unsure what to put in the 'application' variable. I tried 'celery flower --broker=redis://localhost' and 'celery flower" but neither worked

What do i need to do to get it working as a daemon??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could keep it is as a command line program and run it under the [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) daemon. This is a common solution in the python world (although supervisord works with any command, not just python), and I use it all the time.

Supervisord makes the program think it is still running in a terminal. There are many examples how to use supervisord, but one that I use for a python proxy server can be found [here](http://jorgenmodin.net/index_html/archive/2010/11/30/novnc-vnc-screen-sharing-in-the-web-browser), scroll down to "Installing the proxy server as a service".

Comment: supervisord does not work with Python3. Any other solution?

Comment: @DavidD. I use Circus from Mozilla instead of Supervisor, works on Python2, Python3 and Python4, even though 4 hasn't been made it, it is just that great.

Answer (score 23):

It is preferably to run flower as a daemon using systemd. Supervisord is not compatible with Python3 that has become a new [best practice](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/which-python/#the-state-of-python-3-2). Moreover, systemd is a [standard process manager](https://www.linuxvoice.com/linux-101-get-the-most-out-of-systemd/) for most of the modern Linux distributions.

I use systemd as a daemon for flower in Ubuntu 16.04. Though I believe the set up won't be much different for other distributions.

1. Create a systemd configuration file called, for example, `flower.service`. In my case, it is located in `/etc/systemd/system` folder. It should contain:

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description=Flower Celery Service

   [Service]
   User=your_user
   Group=www-data
   WorkingDirectory=/var/www/project-working-directory
   ExecStart=/home/user/miniconda3/envs/virtualenv/bin/flower --port=5555  --loglevel=info -A yourproject
   Restart=on-failure
   Type=simple

   [Install]
   WantedBy=multi-user.target
   ```

Basically, you may set all of the available options like in a terminal. By the way, you should use flower under [virtual environment](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/overview.html). Make sure that your user have privileges over a working directory.

2. Reload systemd daemon
   `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`
3. Start a flower daemon
   `sudo systemctl start flower`

That's all! [This](https://eklitzke.org/production-tornado-deployment-with-systemd) nice tutorial helped me get through the configuration process.